# Sysmalloc: Assertion error using vectors

Tags: c++, vector, malloc, c++14, assertion

While doing this codility [lesson](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/6-sorting/max_product_of_three/) I've encountered some strange behaviour.

```
int solution(std::vector<int> &A) {
    std::vector<int> B, C;
    B.resize(std::count_if(A.begin(), A.end(), [](int x){return x < 0;}));
    C.resize(A.size() - B.size());
    std::copy(A.begin(), std::remove_copy_if(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), [](int x){return x > 0;}), C.begin());

    std::sort(A.begin(), A.end(), [](int x, int y){return x > y;});
    std::sort(B.begin(), B.end(), [](int x, int y){return x < y;});
    std::sort(C.begin(), C.end(), [](int x, int y){return x > y;});
```

This part of function splits a vector into two vectors, 1st with positive and 2nd with negative integers. All vectors are then sorted in a wanted order.

```
    if (B.size() >= static_cast<size_t>(2)) {
        if (C.size() >= static_cast<size_t>(3)) {
            if (B[0] * B[1] > C[1] * C[2])
                return B[0] * B[1] * C[0];
        } else if(C.size() == static_cast<size_t>(2)) {
            if (B[0] * B[1] > C[0] * C[1])
                return B[0] * B[1] * C[0];
        }
    }
    return A[0] * A[1] * A[2];
}
```

This part finds the biggest multpily product of 3 elements from an input vector.

After reaching return the function crashes and I get an error:

```
a.out: malloc.c:2394: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) &&
old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) &&
((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Aborted
```

I tried to debug it and I saw that after return statement the debugger jumps to the B & C vectors declaration, and later jumps to the exiting curly brackets.
I have never seen something, like that and I want to understand it. I'm using g++-7.1 under linux and compile with --std=c++14 flag.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You most likely go out of bounds *somewhere*. It doesn't have to be in the code you show. You have to use a memory debugger (like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)) on a debug-build (with the `-g` flag) to find out more.

Comment: My debugger often "jumps back to declarations" for the implicit destructor calls that must happen when exiting a block scope.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the lambdas here:

```
B.resize(std::count_if(A.begin(), A.end(), [](int x){return x < 0;}));
```

and here:

```
std::copy(A.begin(),
          std::remove_copy_if(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(),
                              [](int x){return x > 0;}),
          C.begin());
```

have to complement each other if you want to be sure that `std::remove_copy_if` will have enough space in `B`. They do not - both return `false` for `0`.

But mainly, the problem is that `std::remove_copy_if` returns `B.end()` in our case (after fixing the problem above), which is incompatible with `A.begin()`. I recommend breaking this statement down, as I got confused, too.

`std::remove_copy_if` does not modify the input range, it is only `std::copy_if` with negated predicate - another misunderstanding, it seems.

---

It looks like you just wanted to partition `A`, while keeping the elements in order. You sort all three vectors afterwards, which means you can sort `A` first, and then use `std::lower_bound`/`std::upper_bound` of `0` and continue with the algorithm without using `B` and `C` - using some iterator arithmetic instead of indexing.

Comment: Thank you sir, actually the lambdas have to be different. As you said remove_copy _if is a negated pred. Actually I gotta change it to return x >= 0; Thank you for pointing out that it returns B.end() iterator. I haven't noticed that.